# How to make loop end once the last element in the array meets condition?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, methods, parameters

In my bouncing ball program, it asks the user to insert a number of balls which will be displayed on the screen and will start at the top of the canvas then drop and bounce on a line on the bottom of the canvas.

When *finished = true*, the animation will stop. So far the animation stops once the X position of the first ball goes past 550. How do I make the animation end once the X position of EVERY ball is more than 550?

```
public void multiBounce(int numBalls)
{
    BouncingBall[] balls;
    balls = new BouncingBall[numBalls];

    int x = 50;
    int y = 150;

    for (int i = 0; i < balls.length; i++){


          balls[i] = new BouncingBall(x, y, 16, Color.blue, ground, myCanvas);
          x = x + 20;
          y = y - 30;
          balls[i].draw();  
    }

    boolean finished =  false;

    while(!finished) {

     for (int i = 0; i < balls.length; i++){

           balls[i].move();

    }

     for (int i = 0; i < balls.length; i++){
         if (balls[i].getXPosition() >= 550){

             finished = true;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a `break` to exit a loop.

Comment: You are currently setting finished to true if *any* ball has a position `>=` 550. Instead, set `finished = true` first, and set it to false if any ball has a position `< 550`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check for every ball whether it is beyond your desired position. This code snippet should do the work. Just replace the last for loop by the code below.

```
finished=true;
for (int i = 0; i < balls.length; i++){ 
    if (balls[i].getXPosition() >= 550){  
        finished = finished && true; }
    else{
        finished=false;
        break;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `break` statement. When its encountered inside a `loop`, the `loop` is immediately terminated and the program control resumes at the next statement following the `loop`. For more details see [Branching Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html)

```
public void multiBounce(int numBalls)
    {
        BouncingBall[] balls;
        balls = new BouncingBall[numBalls];

        int x = 50;
        int y = 150;

        for (int i = 0; i < balls.length; i++){


            balls[i] = new BouncingBall(x, y, 16, Color.blue, ground, myCanvas);
            x = x + 20;
            y = y - 30;
            balls[i].draw();
        }

        boolean finished =  false;

        while(!finished) {

            for (int i = 0; i < balls.length; i++){

                balls[i].move();

            }

            for (int i = 0; i < balls.length; i++){
                if (balls[i].getXPosition() < 550){
                    finished = false;
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    finished = true;
                }
            }

            }
        }
```